# JavaScript - Splitting a tileset image to be stored in 2D Image() array

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this image:

[image]

and I have this 2D array `tiles[]` .. and using `Image()` function... how can do I use the (what I assume be best way?) `for` loop to add each tile into the `array` so `tile[0]` through however many there are is read and used as `Image()` objects later to be painted on HTML5 canvas?

Comment: You have to know how many pixels wide and high each square is

Comment: This is hard to test because it's from imgur.  It deals with cross-domain issues.  This needs to be on your local server.

Comment: I have it saved on my computer jeschafe...

Comment: I understand it's just hard for us to test because you can't save the file on jsfiddle or anything like that

Comment: Can't you test it on localhost? I don't know what else to do there.

Comment: Why do you want to split it? You could easily write a function which acts on an index (or coordiantes) and one single image element.

Comment: My point is that in the end you'll use `putImageData`. This method is able to draw only sections of the "input-image". So my idea is, don't split the image when it's not needed, just have a function that is able to call `putImageData` correctly. And this could be accomplished by just transforming some input data, e.g coordinates or running number of a tile.

Comment: @weka I'll try to give an example shortly, though I named the wrong method. It's [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would..

- Figure out how many tiles wide and high this image is
- Draw the image to a canvas in memory, and use the context to get image data.
- Loop through and subimage each tile, storing in an array.

Assuming:

> imageWidth, imageHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight

All describe what their names suggest, and:

**EDIT: Added image load as per comment, fixed wrongly name `ImageWidth` and `ImageHeight` to `imageWidth` and `imageHeight`**

**EDIT: Performing code inside `imageObj.onload` as the image is drawn here, drawImage() from origin (0,0)**

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = "tilesetImageLocationHere";

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
```

Then, split up your image into a list of tile data..

```
    var tilesX = imageWidth / tileWidth;
    var tilesY = imageHeight / tileHeight;
    var totalTiles = tilesX * tilesY;        
    var tileData = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<tilesY; i++)
    {
      for(var j=0; j<tilesX; j++)
      {           
        // Store the image data of each tile in the array.
        tileData.push(ctx.getImageData(j*tileWidth, i*tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight));
      }
    }
    //From here you should be able to draw your images back into a canvas like so:
    ctx.putImageData(tileData[0], x, y);
  }
```

Comment: What about the image of tileset to load from?

Comment: See edits. Load an image into a canvas element and use it's context from there. Does this answer you question?

Comment: Here's what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/1tUgRxQh - The console.log near the end spits out ImageData but then I get `Uncaught TypeError: Type error ` when I try to `putImageData`

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. See the edits. The problem is that the `imageObj.onload` is being called AFTER the rest of the script is executed, and there has been nothing drawn to the canvas. I have simply encapsulate the remaining script in the `imageObj.onload()` function scope to remedy this.

Answer (score 0):

ok I did this on my localhost: it should give you a base at least.  I think you should be able to use this straight outta the box but you might have to make a few calculation adjustments for it depending on what you want. I just don't think it's neccessary to spend thee time to perfect it to your example:

You'll obviously have to point the image to your own image.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('fakeCanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = '/theImage.png';
        var tiles = [];
        var  imageTileNumWidth = 23;
        var imageTileNumHeight = 21;

img.onload = function(){
  var imageWidth = img.width;
  var imageHeight = img.height;
  sndCanvasWidth = imageWidth/imageTileNumWidth;
  sndCanvasHeight = imageHeight/imageTileNumHeight;
  canvas.width = imageWidth;
  canvas.height = imageHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);
  var sndCanvas = document.getElementById('drawCanvas');
  sndCanvas.width=sndCanvasWidth;
  sndCanvas.height=sndCanvasHeight;
  var i=0;
  var j=0;
  var t=0;
    for(i=0;i<imageWidth;i+=sndCanvasWidth){
      for(j=0;j<imageHeight;j+=sndCanvasHeight){
            var myImageData = ctx.getImageData(j,i,sndCanvasWidth,sndCanvasHeight);     
            var ctx2 = sndCanvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx2.putImageData(myImageData,0,0);
            tiles.push(myImageData);  
      }
    }
};
    });
  </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="fakeCanvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="drawCanvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```