# JavaScript - Uncaught TypeError: Type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to break a spritesheet and well, it's not putting it into a 2D array like it should. At the end of my code, near the console.log, it spits out ImageData...but when it tries to putImageData... I get `Uncaught TypeError: Type error`

Help?

and here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("Client setup...");
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.tabIndex = 0;
    canvas.focus();
    console.log("Client focused.");

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = "./images/all_tiles.png";
    imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    };

    var allLoaded = 0;
    var tilesX = ImageWidth / tileWidth;
    var tilesY = ImageHeight / tileHeight;
    var totalTiles = tilesX * tilesY;        
    var tileData = [totalTiles]; // Array with reserved size
    for(var i=0; i<tilesY; i++)
    {
      for(var j=0; j<tilesX; j++)
      {           
        // Store the image data of each tile in the array.
        tileData.push(context.getImageData(j*tileWidth, i*tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight));
        allLoaded++;
      }
    }

    if (allLoaded == totalTiles) {
    console.log("All done: " + allLoaded);
    console.log(tileData[1]);
    context.putImageData(tileData[0], 0 ,0); // Sample paint
    }


});
```

error happens at `context.putImageData(tileData[0], 0 ,0); // Sample paint`

Here is example fiddle of code above http://jsfiddle.net/47XUA/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the first element of `tileData` is not an `ImageData` object, **it's a plain number**!  When you initialized your array you used:

```
var tileData = [totalTiles];
```

This means that `tileData[0]` is equal to the value of `totalTiles`, which is the number `483`.  You are providing a number instead of an `ImageData` object to `putImageData`, and the browser is throwing an error in confusion.  If you look at any other element in the rest of your array, you'll see it is successfully being populated with `ImageData` objects as you expect; only the first element in the array is a number.

You probably meant to do:

```
var tileData = new Array(totalTiles);
```

which would create an array with the specified `length` property, instead of setting the first value in the array to a number.  Personally, I would run some performance tests to see if that is even useful; you may be just as well using `var tileData = [];`

Comment: To clarify, it still produces the same `Type error`?  My fork does not (in Chrome and FF): http://jsfiddle.net/HBzH7/

Comment: I don't see `context.putImageData(tileData[1], 0 ,0);` painting the image on the canvas?

Comment: Also.. apparently calling it to draw in another function gives that same `Type error`.

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean by "calling it to draw in another function" -- can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Possibly your failure-to-draw issue is caused by failure-to-read due to [same-origin restrictions](http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules) on getImageData, but that is appropriate for a new question.  However, if you've discovered a new `Type error` problem, that is still on-topic for this question.

Comment: Something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/9bFGk/ I still don't know why it's not painting onto canvas...

Comment: I don't see any `Type error` in my console.  (Can you tell me what OS/browser is still producing a `Type error` in your latest fiddle?) Instead, in Firefox I see a `code: 18` error, `"The operation is not secure"`, which is probably related to the same-origin security that I linked above and is outside the scope of this current question.  As far as I can tell, your `Type error` problems are solved (if not,  let me know OS/browser). Open a new question to solve this new issue related to cross-domain image security -- also, try it on your actual site (not on the fiddle) to see that solves it.

Comment: Vista... (I know)/ Chrome v21

Comment: Okay, so, just one final check: http://jsfiddle.net/AtHRq/.  This should produce an alert box with a "Type error" message when you run it. If you don't see an alert, your problem is not related to the Type error, and this question is resolved.  If do see the alert, I'm afraid I can't help you any further, as I don't see any such error.  Perhaps it's a race condition?

Comment: Right, that's what I've been saying -- the error that's stopping your program is no longer a Type error.  It's probably a [cross-domain security error](http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules). (See also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception).)  You have fixed your original problem.  Your program is **not** encountering a Type error any longer, because that issue is fixed.  You are now are blocked by a completely different, unrelated error. Feel free to open a new question!

Comment: Your issues with **cross-domain security** can be resolved in jsFiddle by referencing an image on their page instead. Cheap hack but easy for testing. I used **"../img/logo.png"** and had no dramas. By using new `Array(size)` and `push()` together you are doubling the size of the array, and the elements from `tileData[0]` to `tileData[size]` are not going to be the right type. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

A type error is caused when a variable or object passed into a statement is not of a type that is expected for that command and can’t be converted into something that is valid.

See [here](http://www.typeerror.com/index.php/javascript-typeerror/) for a full definition of the error.

So most likely that context or tileData is in an incorrect format or is null or undefined

Answer (score 0):

It might be a *racing condition*. You are using drawImage only when the image `./images/all_tiles.png` has been loaded. But you are using the image data on the context **before** the onload fired. Try to move everything which is after the onload handler into the onload handler.

Comment: No, that did not work. Same error. I put it between the onload.

Comment: do you have an online example of this?

Comment: I get a different error running your jsFiddle in FF13: `The operation is insecure` caused by this statement `context.getImageData(j*tileWidth, i*tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight)`.

Comment: That's weird. I ran it and I get `Uncaught TypeError: Type error `.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `imageObj.onload()` function is being called AFTER the rest of the script is executed.

This means that queries to `getImageData()` are returning undefined, as there is no image data in the canvas when called.

A simple way to fix this is to encapuslate the remaining script in the `imageObj.onload` function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log("Client setup...");
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.tabIndex = 0;
canvas.focus();
console.log("Client focused.");

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = "./images/all_tiles.png";

imageObj.onload = function() {

  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

  var allLoaded = 0;
  var tilesX = imageWidth / tileWidth;
  var tilesY = imageHeight / tileHeight;
  var totalTiles = tilesX * tilesY;        
  var tileData = new Array(); // Array with NO reserved size
  for(var i=0; i<tilesY; i++)
  {
    for(var j=0; j<tilesX; j++)
    {           
      // Store the image data of each tile in the array.
      tileData.push(context.getImageData(j*tileWidth, i*tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight));
      allLoaded++;
    }
  }

  context.putImageData(tileData[0], 0 ,0); // Sample paint
}; // End 'imageObj.onload()' scope.

}); // End document ready function scope.
```

This ensures that any calls to `getImageData()` are made after `context.drawImage()`

You may also have a problem here that you are not drawing the image to cover the canvas. Change the line:

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

to

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
```

**EDIT: You also had `ImageWidth` and `imageWidth` (same for height). Rename these.**

**EDIT: Reserving the Array size here with `new Array(totalTiles)` was causing an issue. When we pushed new tile images to the array, it pushed to the end of the pre-allocated array (starting at `tileData[totalTiles]`). This is easily fixed by removing the size argument. Otherwise instead of using `push()` we could copy the image data into the array in a loop, eg: `tileData[n] = getImageData(...)`, starting at `tileData[0]`.**

Comment: Weiiiiiird.. Here have a look at this. http://pastebin.com/0Un9f6Vc There is two versions there, the previous version is your code. You can compare them line for line. That works for me. I am drawing the jsFiddle image (from the top left corner of the page) into the canvas, subimaging a section of white and drawing that back over the image. You should see the jsFiddle image in the output missing a piece from (10,0) through to (30,30)

Comment: I don't believe OP ever used `new Array(totalTiles)`.  He used `[totalTiles]` (erroneously) and then just `[]`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, confused as this question is happening in two places: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533606/javascript-splitting-a-tileset-image-to-be-stored-in-2d-image-array

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome.

```
context.drawImage(spritesheet.image, 0, 0, 4608, 768);// Works
context.drawImage(spritesheet.image, 768, 0, 768, 768, 4608, 768); // Doesn't work: Uncaught TypeError: Type error
```

Thank you!